# What's the best way of opening a modal window and have the opening function wait until the modal is closed (without using frameworks)?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have some code I use when I want to open modal boxes in javascript, but up until now the initial function sets up the modal box and then exits, and the "return" button in the modal window calls a second function.   This works, but is a bit clumsy (it means I need to pass all the variables I haven't finished with either in hidden forms or global variables).

I know that javascript is supposed to be asynchronous and what I'm asking for (basically like the way modal forms used to work in VB) is probably tantamount to blasphemy, but I'd still like to know how to do it.

I have a suspicion that promises might be the answer, but I can't work out how to adapt the usual examples that are given (timeouts or file accesses); I'm almost certainly missing something because I've never really been able to work out the USP of promises, despite how enthusiastic people got about them when they came out.

At the moment my code doesn't use any frameworks or jquery - I'd rather keep jquery out of it if possible (in the past certain bugs in my code tend to lead to errors inside the library, which makes debugging really horrible) and I really don't want to have to learn a framework if there is a simple pure javascript workaround.

EDIT (trying to implement @CtrlAltDel 's suggestions):

```
function JPrompt(sTitle,sDefault=""){
    var divPrompt=document.createElement("div")
    divPrompt.id='div_id'
    divPrompt.innerHTML=sTitle+"<form><input type=number id='texPromptNumber' /><input type=button id='butConfirm' value=OK data-info='3' /></form>"
    document.body.appendChild(divPrompt);
    
    var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    btnFunc = function (e) {
        if (val === "Ok") {
          var input = form.querySelector("INPUT, TEXTAREA");
          if (!input) input = "true";
          else input = input.value;
          resolve(input);
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }       
    }
    
  });
    document.getElementById('butConfirm').addEventListener("click",btnFunc);
        
    p.then(function(res){
            result=document.getElementById('texPromptNumber').value
            alert(result)
            document.getElementById('divPrompt').outerHTML=""
    });
}
```

- I don't know if that addEventListener is in the right place; I had to make btnFunc global so that that code could see it.
- This still ran straight through to later code without waiting for a button press.  So I tried this:

```
function JPrompt(sTitle,sDefault=""){
     function setPrompt(){
     var divPrompt=document.createElement("div")
     divPrompt.id='div_id'
     divPrompt.innerHTML=sTitle+"<form><input type=number id='texPromptNumber' /><input type=button id='butConfirm' value=OK data-info='3' /></form>"
     document.body.appendChild(divPrompt);
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            btnFunc = function (e) {
                resolve(input)
            };
      });   
        document.getElementById('butConfirm').addEventListener("click",btnFunc);
    }
    
        
    


    async function getPrompt(){
        var result=await setPrompt()
        result=document.getElementById('texPromptNumber').value
        alert(result)
        document.getElementById('divPrompt').outerHTML=""
    }
    getPrompt();
}
```

And pretty much the same thing happens.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is by using a `Promise`. You may also want to use an async function so that you can `await` the results of the promise

```
  let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    let btnFunc = function (e) {
        if (val === "Ok") {
          var input = form.querySelector("INPUT, TEXTAREA");
          if (!input) input = "true";
          else input = input.value;
          resolve(input);
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
        $(dialogDiv).detach();
    }
  }
```

This is just a demonstration. And you need to add an Ok and a Cancel button to the div, and use addEventListener('click') with the buttons to activate btnFunc

on the other end, you can use `var res = await p;` or p.then(function(res) {...}) to get the results set in the promise once the promise is fulfilled

There is also a non-standard "Dialog" tag in newer versions of Chrome and FireFox that you can use

--- Edit ---

If the modal part is important, there is an example of how you can do this here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

It involves creating a background layer to make it work and toggling it on and off, which is to intensive for my blood.

Comment: Still a bit confused I'm afraid - have edited the question with the code I've got so far.